# jQuery get all content inside id and class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a way to search and get all the content that's after id="mydata" and class="myheader"

So:

```
function findit() {
var str = `<div id="mydata"><div class="myheader"><p>Get all <strong>this</strong> content</p></div></div>`;
console.log(str);

}
```

So in this case str needs to return:

```
<p>Get all <strong>this</strong> content</p>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `$('.myheader').text()`?

Comment: I need to first look for #mydata ... then in there look for .myheader as there are more than one myheader in the html

Comment: `$('#mydata').find('.myheader').text()`. Or `$('#mydata').find('.myheader').html()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would convert that to html and get the data that way, so:

```js
function findit() {
  let tmpDiv = document.createElement('div')
  tmpDiv.innerHTML = `<div id="mydata"><div class="myheader"><p>Get all <strong>this</strong> content</p></div></div>`

  let myHeader = tmpDiv.querySelector('#mydata .myheader')
  console.log(myHeader.innerHTML)
}

findit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your html string in `$()` and use jQuery methods on it the same way you would in the dom

```js
function findit() {
  var str = `<div id="mydata"><div class="myheader"><p>Get all <strong>this</strong> content</p></div></div>`;
  console.log($(str).filter('#mydata').find('.myheader').html());

}

findit()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```